# Program or Firefox plugin to keep cookie alive?

Tags: windows, firefox, plugins, cookies

I need to make some cookie to stay alive forever, because some website I use doesn't have "remember me" option when logging in.

Is there any plugin, or program for this?

Answer (score 1):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/edit-cookies/

> Instead of using auto form-completer, using this add-on made it possible to stay logged in to website forever

Comment: +1 - this is great. I didn't even know this existed. Thanks

Comment: i dont think this worked, i set the cookie expire in far future, but right after i reopened browser, my login information was gone. i guess it is more complicated system than just one single cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't seem like it *must* be about cookies - more that you would like the form details to be saved. If that is the case, you can use something like:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/  (although I use this tool, it does not save "quick login" style passwords but you'll have to try it).

General details about form management: 
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-passwords

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind setting an expiration date of a cookie is that your browser should automatically delete the cookie once the server won't accept it anymore.

While you can prevent your browser from deleting it automatically after some given time has passed, a correctly set up website won't accept the expired cookie and, once you visit it again, issue a command to delete it "manually".

Accepting expired cookies would be a huge security risk. Everybody that managed to sniff one of your cookies could use it indefinitely, without any way of stopping him.

Comment: Hm, good point. But is this an answer? Might you know any tools that allow me to login indefinitely to the website (without enabling firefox password rememberer, i only want to remember 1 password, and not ask it for every website).

Comment: You asked *Is there any plugin, or program for this?*. My answer is no. It's impossible to *stay* logged in, as long as the website is configured properly. I suppose you could log in automatically every time you visit the website, but that would have to be a custom solution for that specific website.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried any of them, but there are several addons for Firefox that purport to do this by periodically reloading a page in your browser. It looks like the only one that is compatible with modern Firefox versions is mSession Keeper https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/msession-keeper/.

There's also this highly rated addon for Chrome called "Staying Alive": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/staying-alive-for-google/lhobbakbeomfcgjallalccfhfcgleinm/reviews?hl=en-US